# java.awt is missing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jwt

(On Ubuntu Linux) as you see from the screenshot, `java.awt` is missing in the list of Eclipse:

[image]

I tried different versions of JDK, including 17. See also my configuration dialog where I try to add `awt`:

[image]

How to make Eclipse see `java.awt`? (Now it produces errors when I try to use `java.awt`.)

Comment: AWT is part of the java.desktop module: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/module-summary.html

Comment: @Puce How to install java.desktop on Ubuntu?

Comment: just click `java.desktop`, expand the node, then you can find `java.awt`. (Default existing in JDK 9+ ~ JDK 17). You do not need to change anything.

Comment: @porton, if you use JDK 9+ ~ JDK 17, it will show java module name, not package. you must select one module like `java.desktop` then expand it, then it will show packages under the module.

Comment: It worked after switching to JDK 17. Why doesn't it work with JDK 19 and JDK 20?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Your comment is misleading. headless JDK installs exist, but they _still_ have `javax.swing` and `java.awt` packages. These classes do not disappear in headless environments or installations. They are 'headless' in the sense that attempting to do anything UI related with them results in a swift `HeadlessException`. Point is, "I cannot find the java.awt package" is not answered by ".. perhaps you have a headless install". ".. perhaps you have a headless install" is the correct answer to: "I got a `HeadlessException` - how come?".

Comment: @rzwitserloot noted, thanks. I'll delete my misleading comment.

Answer (score 0):

> (On Ubuntu Linux) as you see from the screenshot, java.awt is missing in the list of Eclipse:

You're confused. **You already have `java.awt` - there is NOTHING you need to do!!** - but read on, I think I know what you're confused about.

That list you pasted into your question is *a list of modules*. `java.awt` is not a module name and never has been. You're thinking of the `java.awt` in e.g. `java.awt.Button`, which is *a package name*. Not a module name.

The `java.awt` package lives in the `java.desktop` module which *you already have* (it's in your pasted list. Regardless, **all** JDKs have this module unless it is treeshaking which is highly unlikely. Even headless JDKs have this package; it's simply that interacting with most of the code in `java.awt` would cause a `HeadlessException` if you tried to use AWT on a headless environment / with a 'headless' JDK installation).

Thus, **there is nothing you have to do - you already have it**.

Let me take a guess as to what you are confused about:

By default, eclipse *ignores* AWT. As in, the auto-complete dialog and 'find type' dialog *do not show AWT classes even though they are available*.

Try it: Type `class Test { java.awt.Button b = null; }` and note how *this code compiles fine without error - no need to install anything*.

To 'fix' that, you open the preferences window of eclipse, type '`type filter`' in the filterbox (you're looking for `Java` > `Appearance` > `Type filters`), and *uncheck* `java.awt` which you'll find in the filterlist and checked if you have a standard eclipse installation.

Eclipse disables it by default for good reason:

- `java.awt` is mostly obsolete; java has 3 local-desktop GUI frameworks (AWT, Swing, and JavaFX), and AWT is by far the least used (and oldest) one.
- The type names in the package clash with common names in other packages. For example, `java.awt.List` is a thing. The java ecosystem at large means, literally, `java.util.List` instead of `java.awt.List` in 99.999% of all cases someone types `List` in eclipse anywhere on the planet. Nevertheless, if you try to fix imports on `List`, eclipse is forced to ask you if you wanted `java.awt.List` or `java.util.List`, which is annoying for everybody, hence, eclipse, by default, acts like `java.awt` does not exist for such type searches.

NB: Starting a new desktop client in AWT in 2023 seems.. unlikely to be what you really want to do here. A further guess is that you are following a literally 20 year old tutorial. It's rather likely the true answer you are looking for is 'use something else'. At the very least, swing (`javax.swing` package, also in `java.desktop` module, also already installed). Possibly JavaFX (that does require a separate dep/install). Probably: Nevermind local desktop, build a webapp.

Answer (score 0):

In src area you may have module-info.java.
In my case I have a project named Test.
This made Eclipse to include java.desktop:

```
module Test {
    requires java.desktop;
}
```